# How do I create a serverless template from a local boiler template

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I have a boiler template saved in my local. How do I create a template using it? I tried the below command, but it did not work:

```
serverless create --template-path '.\Boiler plate\' --name UserRegistration
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
at validateString (internal/validators.js:120:11)
at Object.join (path.js:375:7).....
.........
```

None of the solutions I find online worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says the serverless command argument `path` is undefined. On the `serverless create` [documentation page](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/create/), there is an example listed that says:

```
serverless create --template-path path/to/my/template/folder --path path/to/my/service --name my-new-service
```

> This will copy the path/to/my/template/folder folder into path/to/my/service and rename the service to my-new-service.

In order to solve your problem, you need to provide a valid `template-path` pointing to a local Serverless template and provide a 'target path' using `--path` to which your template will be copied. So you command will probably look like this:

```
serverless create --template-path '.\Boiler plate' --path /target/for/your/template.yml --name UserRegistration
```

Note: I haven't adjusted `'.\Boiler plate\'` in this command. Are you sure it's correct using a backslash `\` after `.` ?

Comment: Hi @hesse. Thank you for your reply.Yes, the slash may or may not be used. I am getting the folowwing error when I am trying to run `serverless create --template-path '.Boiler plate' --path './CompanyRegistration/serverless.yml' --name CompanyRegistration` 
Error: `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'serverless/aws' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Comment: Got it. I didn't know I had to run the serverless create from inside the boiler plate